# Changing the text of all the buttons on a form in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Call me crazy but for the life of me I cannot make this work.  I have the following code:

```
    Dim cControl As Control
    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is Button) Then
            cControl.ForeColor = Color.Black
            cControl.Font = New Font(cControl.Font, FontStyle.Regular)
        End If
    Next cControl

    Me.ActiveControl.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    Me.ActiveControl.Font = New Font(Me.ActiveControl.Font, FontStyle.Bold)
```

I am trying to make the font black and regular for all of the buttons on the form (there are a lot) and the button just clicked, bolded and blue.

The second part of the code works (making the font bold and blue), it's the first that is not simply working.

What am I missing?

Comment: posted code works fine for me. I opened a new form, added a button and copied/pasted it 6 more times (so names are Button1 through Button7). Added a click event for Button1 then added Button2 through Button7 to the same event, and pasted the code in above. What do you mean by it doesn't work? Every single button will change itself to bold and blue, but the loop isn't doing anything? Try stepping through it?

Comment: you dont have to create a new font object for each button - thats pretty expensive

Comment: I currently have the code residing in a private sub  ... would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: If the buttons are on panels or tabs that loop wont find them; those guy's parent is that container control, not the form.

Comment: I think your Button is nested in other controls. You'll have to check all nested controls too.

Comment: @Plutonix good point. I would try stepping through the loop and making sure it's actually hitting the buttons.

Comment: ...or just look at the form in Document OutLine view, it will reveal who is parent of what

Comment: Nevermind I found my problem.  The buttons are in a group box so I had to reference the group box directly

Comment: CZechDeveloper ... that was exactly correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found my problem. The buttons are in a group box so I had to reference the group box directly

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it like that before, but I have used Linq to accomplish what you want.

```
Dim btn() As Button
btn = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)().Where(Function(c) c.Name.Contains("")).ToArray()
```

This will basically create an array of buttons from your form, then you can just loop through each one.

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < btn.Count
                btn(i).Enabled = True
                btnText(i).BackColor = Color.DarkOliveGreen
                btnText(i).ForeColor = Color.White
                i += 1
End While
```

If you have a naming convention for your buttons and want to only change certain buttons where the empty quotes are you can have "btnTest".

Then you will have an index of any button that contains the text "btnTest" in it. So that would include "btnTest1", "btnTest2", "btnTestAnything1234" etc.

Hope this helps and you can use it!